# Confusing WP page load with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jquery, wordpress

My site is http://armandwho.com/site

I'm using the Adv. Ajax Page Loader Plugin in order to keep my background vid & music uninterrupted while browsing.

I'm having trouble with the "LOOK" page. When navigating to it from the homepage (1st link), the gallery doesn't load at all. However, when you refresh or go directly to the page URL it works.

Within the plugin, there is an area for jQuery reload codes, which I think will load the needed scripts that don't get loaded when using the nav.

Can anyone make sense of what script I might need to "reload" to get my gallery working with this Ajax plugin?

Help is supremely appreciated!

Joe

Comment: That's a _lot_ of JavaScript code to sift through.  A good reminder of why I _don't_ use WP or its plugins.

Comment: Haven't looked into your issue too much. The music is great though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loved the music, so I decided to look into the problem a bit.

I stepped through the code for the plugin as it tried to load the page and came across this line:

```
//Nothing like good old pure JavaScript...
document.getElementById(AAPL_content).innerHTML = output;
```

..which is a problem because the javascript in the script tags isn't going to be run. You could change it to:

```
//Nothing like good old pure JavaScript...
jQuery(document.getElementById(AAPL_content)).html(output);
```

..and jQuery will handle the dirty work.

Comment: Wow thanks @walkerneo! I'm gonna give this a shot as soon as I can. Many thanks also for digging the tunes!

Comment: thanks again @Walkerneo, I tried modifying that line as you suggested but the Ajax loading plugin stopped working altogether. This is a tough one!

Comment: @Mojoe, Hmm. There are two places that line of code is used, once at 251 and once at 309 - both should be replaced. Although, I don't know why it would stop working.. I was testing this on chrome, what browser was it not working in? The plugin is pretty hacky in the way it works, and though I don't have much WP experience, I'm willing to guess this is one of many problems that you're going to run into unless you plan on having a very static site.

Comment: thanks again! That seemed to do it! All to do now is some styling to get it full screen like it is when using the direct url. This is great! The reason I've resorted to using that Ajax plugin is to keep the background video playing without interruption. I'm wondering if a simple iframe for the background would be a good option though.